# SignalR returns "Connection ID required" when ran in an AWS ECS container

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, signalr, kestrel-http-server

I am trying to get a .Net Core 3.1 SignalR Web API with an Angular front end to work with websockets.

The code works perfectly fine when ran locally, either from within in the IDE or via `docker run`. However, once the code gets deployed to an ECS instance in AWS behind an API Gateway the web sockets refuse to connect.

I setup my mappings like so:

```
app.UsePathBase("/ui");
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
               "default",
              "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}")
             .RequireCors(PolicyName);
    endpoints.MapHub<SessionHub>("/ws/session");
    endpoints.MapHub<SessionsHub>("/ws/sessions");
});
```

And on the client I connect to the hub like so:

```
this.sessionsHubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl(`${window.origin}/ws/sessions`, {
    skipNegotiation: true,
    transport: HttpTransportType.WebSockets,
    accessTokenFactory: () => this.getAccessToken()
  })
  .withAutomaticReconnect()
  .build();
```

The following Fiddler trace shows the initial HTTP request to initialize the websocket connection and the error being returned by kestrel.
[image]

I tweaked my web socket middleware for handling the access token to also `Console.Write` some additional debugging statements that I think might prove insightful:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
{
    var request = httpContext.Request;
    Console.WriteLine($"Starting connection id: {httpContext.Connection.Id}");

    // web sockets cannot pass headers so we must take the access token from query param and
    // add it to the header before authentication middleware runs
    if (request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/ws", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        &&
        request.Query.TryGetValue("access_token", out var accessToken))
    {
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {accessToken}");
    }

    try
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine($"Connection Id: {httpContext.Connection.Id}");
        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());

        await _next(httpContext);

        sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine($"Status code {httpContext.Response.StatusCode}"); <-- this line
        sb.AppendLine($"Connection Id: {httpContext.Connection.Id}");    <-- and this line
        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        throw;
    }
}
```

And in the AWS logs you can see that the connection Id is present but is being ignored by the EndpointMiddleware(?) for some reason.

[image]

Any idea what could be causing this? Two ideas I have yet to be able to rule out are:

1. The HTTP/S termination at our API gateway is confusing Kestrel since the browser client is building the socket request under HTTPS, but as far as Kestrel is concerned everything is communicating over HTTP?
2. `app.UsePathBase("/ui");` is confusing Kestrel and all the web socket paths should actually be /ui/ws/session?

Comment: In Azure you have to turn on AAR Affinity token which ensures that a client stays on the same instance of your application. So what's happening is the first request is going to one instance, then the second request is going to another instance. The other instance wasn't involved with the initial request, so it's expecting a connection ID because it thinks it's the first request. So look for settings that deal with "Session State" and make sure state is persistent.

Comment: I'm guessing the request isn't being forwarded as a websocket request to the server and SignalR thinks you're trying to use LongPolling which doesn't support skip negotiate.

Comment: @andy there is only one container so there are no other instances to go to.

Comment: @Brennan I'm thinking along the lines you are but I have long polling disabled. Something is getting lost in the mix when the socket upgrade request is executed.

Comment: It doesn't matter if long polling is disabled in this case. The "Executing endpoint '/ws/sessions'" log means that the SignalR endpoint is running, and the only time you would get a "Connection ID required" response is if you hit the LongPolling or SSE code path (again disabling longpolling doesn't matter here). And the only reason you should be hitting those for a websocket request is the gateway/proxy is not forwarding the headers correctly for an upgrade request. You said you're using AWS API gateway, and it probably requires some configuration for WebSockets.